# Contar los clics que se le dan a un boton ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de implementar el conteo de clics que se le dan a un botón durante un mes,y guarde ese registro y sea consecutivo, y al llegar al termino del mes, se reinicie y comience de nuevo desde 0

Solo he conseguido el contador de clics cada que le doy clic a mi botón este aumente 1 en 1 por cada clic y que cuando llegue al numero 30 se reinicie a 0

```
public partial class App_Contador : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void aumentoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = int.Parse(casillaTextBox.Text);
        count++;
        casillaTextBox.Text = count.ToString();

        if (casillaTextBox.Text == "31")
        {
            casillaTextBox.Text = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

Podría alguien orientarme para realizar dicha acción, seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: No queda claro que es lo que necesitas, ya que dices que el codigo adjunto te funciona. Que buscas hacer?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera quiero realizar el conteo de los clics que se le da a ese boton y me lo guarde como un registro cada clic, y al termino de un mes el contador reinicie a 0 (asi hayan sido 200-500 clics)

Comment: Entiendo, lo que no me queda claro es algo, quieres guardar en una BD cada click que se haga como un registro diferente, por ejemplo si hago 10 clicks, seran 10 registros? Y lo otro, solo deseas guardar la cantidad de clicks o almacenaras otros datos?

Comment: Te comento rápido espero ser claro, cada que yo de click en el botón me lo registre como folio 001 y el siguiente click me lo guarde como folio 002 y así sucesivamente, y que cuando llegue el final del mes,se haga un corte y el primero del mes siguiente de nuevo inicie con el folio 001, por el momento solo guardaría ese dato

Comment: No lo pongo como respuesta porque quizás no lo sea. Es solo una sugerencia: La mejor forma de recolectar telemetría en una aplicación (Cómo en tu caso), es utilizar software especializado (Para no re-inventar la rueda). Mi recomendación sería utilizar (Por ejemplo) Azure AppInsights: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/monitor. Es muy fácil de implementar y tiene una capa gratuita.

Answer (score 1):

Para conservar los datos en un periodo de tiempo vas a necesitar persistir esa informacion, con lo cual un `archivo` o `base de datos` va a ser necesario

Quizas lo mas simple seria usar una db en `SqlCompact` o `Sqlite`

[Ejemplo de SQLite con .NET y CSharp](https://anexsoft.com/ejemplo-de-sqlite-con-net-y-csharp)

la idea es que puedas usar ado.net para realizar el SELECT y luego el UPDATE

usas el package de nuet

[System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite)

y puedes administrar la db usando la extension del Visual Studio

[SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox)

La idea es que puedas ejecutar una operacion como ser

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("<connection string>"))  
{  
    conn.Open();  

    string query = "UPDATE NombreTabla SET casilla = casilla + 1";  
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);  

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

}
```

la idea es que crees la tabla con una columna del tipo numerica

Para incrementar por mes usarias

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("<connection string>"))  
{  
    conn.Open();  

    string query = "UPDATE NombreTabla SET folio = folio + 1 WHERE mes = @mes";  
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);  
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mes", DateTime.Now.Month);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

}
```

para recuperar el valor en un mes seria

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("<connection string>"))  
{  
    conn.Open();  

    string query = "SELECT folio WHERE mes = @mes";  
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);  
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mes", DateTime.Now.Month);

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

    if(reader.Read()){
        txtFolio.Text = string.Foramt("{0:000}", Convert.ToInt32(reader["folio"]));
    }

}
```

Comment: Que tal Leandro, lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente:
cada que yo de click en el botón me lo registre como folio 001 y el siguiente click me lo guarde como folio 002 y así sucesivamente, y que cuando llegue el final del mes,se haga un corte y el primero del mes siguiente de nuevo inicie con el folio 001. Esto lo puedo lograr usando un BD en SQL Server?

Comment: cuando defines el folio los ceros delantes estan de mas, si quieres que el usuario los vea los aplicas como formato, pero en la db solo registras el numero simple

Comment: podrias en lugar de tener un campo tenes dos uno del mes y otro del folio, ahora edito el codigo para poner un ejemplo de como filtrarias por el mes